# detectAndCompute() method in opencv python gives a CommandLine Error

Tags: python, opencv, llvm

I'm trying the ORB method for feature matching but the `detectAndCompute` method gives an error.

***Code:***

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as 

# display function
def display(img, title=None, cmap='gray'):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 10))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.imshow(img, cmap)
    plt.title(title)
    plt.show()

reeses_printout = cv2.imread("../DATA/reeses_puffs.png", 0)
cereals = cv2.imread("../DATA/many_cereals.jpg", 0)

orb = cv2.ORB_create()
key_points_1, descriptors_1 = orb.detectAndCompute(reeses_printout, mask=None)
key_points_2, descriptors_2 = orb.detectAndCompute(cereals, mask=None)
```

***Error message:***

```
$ python3 feature_matcing.py 
: CommandLine Error: Option 'enable-value-profiling' registered more than once!
LLVM ERROR: inconsistency in registered CommandLine options
```

Comment: This is because more than one OpenCL vendor's `.icd` file points to an implementation using the same LLVM, you get this error. You should statically link LLVM. Please provide your OS system, and version of CV2 and etc. I am using conda manage environment on MacOS, I couldn't reproduce your error.

Comment: I'm using Fedora 30 and I tried to run it on Windows 7 and 8.1 as well and it gives the same error but it works on Jupyter notebook, I have python 3.7.5, the latest version of opencv-python.